# sqlce insert works, but changes doesn't appear in the server express

Tags: sql-server-ce

i wrote first time app combine sqlce database(VS2008 c#):

```
                SqlCeCommand identChange = con.CreateCommand();
                identChange.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT contacts ON";
                SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO contacts (contactID, firstName, cellularNumber) VALUES (1000, @name1 , @number)";
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", name1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", number);
                    identChange.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }

                catch (SqlCeException ex)
                {
                    //log ex
                }

                using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT firstName FROM contacts", con))
                {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string name = reader.GetString(0);
                            Console.WriteLine("there is " + name);
                        }
                        con.Close();
                }
```

my problem is, when i read the table values its seems that the new row inserted properly,
but after it finish, when i look at the table data in the Server Explorer window, the new row doesn't exists

i would like to know what im missing...

Answer (score 0):

How did you open the database file?

Is there any chance you created the database every time the program start?

**EDITED**

You first inserted some data in the database. Execute the program, inserted new data. But new data does not show up in the server explorer, right?

Then, when did your new data is gone? After program exit?

What data read when you execute the program again?

Comment: This is the open code: 

            string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.contactsConnectionString;
            using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))

Comment: i dont think i create it every time because i inserted some values manually and they showen up in the read iteration

Comment: @nyutal I asked open method because you could create new database with connection string. And you inserted some record and succeed to read, this is not the case.

Comment: i played with it little more, it seems that every time i open the table manually in the server explorer window (edit table) it initialize the table. is it make sense?

Comment: @nyutal Ooch.. sorry for that (but not my fault :). It doesn't make sense to me, and I didn't experienced that kind of problems before. How about to reinstall SQL CE? SQL CE can be installed separately. And you could try more recent version of SQL CE. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e497988a-c93a-404c-b161-3a0b323dce24